# Create shared library using gcc

Tags: java, c++, gcc, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have a .cpp (jSide.cpp) file and I want to create a shared library(jside.dll) using the gcc command. I get how to use the gcc command, but I need to include header files that is required for jni. Here are the locations of my header files:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\include
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\include\win32

so can anyone tell me the exact command to create a shared library?

Thanks

Aravind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use -I flag to specify directory of header files.

`C:\>gcc -dll -o JSide.dll -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\include\win32" jSide.cpp`

note that this is one line.